# How to keep Unit of Work abstraction from leaking

Tags: c#, entity-framework, data-access-layer

I am learning about good design practices and came upon the Unit of Work design pattern, along with the Repository. This allows me to keep the application logic from knowing about the persistence details, however there are some corner cases that i'm having some difficulty dealing with.

First of all, behind the IUnitOfWork interface i'm using an implementation that accesses my data using EF. For my queries, i use the Specification design pattern to create query objects that the client can use.

So, the thing is pretty much abstracted from the datasource until now, but here's the deal:
imagine i want to retrieve some data with the AsNoTracking option. How am i supposed to tell my IUnitOfWork implementation that i dont need the resulting objects to be tracked?

Moreover, EF doesn't really support batch CUD, nor Future Queries, but there is an extension that supports. How do i support this in a way that the client code is totally agnostic to the way i persist objects? I might want to use flat files, for all the code cares.

TL;DR;
How do i keep my UnitOfWork abstraction from leaking into my clients? Has anyone dealt with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of this would be accomplished by injecting a repository who's implementation gives out those non-tracked objects or talks read/writes to flat files.

A lot of what the conceptual repository does is at cross purposes with UoW. The repo implementation ends up having a lot of these:

```
public class MyRepository : IWhateverRepository
{
    // ...
    public Customer GetCustomerByName(string customerName)
    {
        using (var db = new MyContext())
        {
            var customer = db.Customers.Where(cust => cust.Name == customerName).SingleOrDefault();
            return customer;
        }
    }

    public Customer StoreCustomer(Customer customer)
    {
        using (var db = new MyContext())
        {
            db.Entry(customer).State = customer.ID == 0 ? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, there isn't a whole lot of usage of the UoW. I think most of the usefulness of EF when using a repository is in not having to write SQL by hand.

However, UoW works well when there is no repository abstraction and the business logic works directly with the entities and the context. For instance in an UI <-> MVC <-> Service Layer scenario you might have the MVC controller instruct the service layer to create a new invoice:

```
IMyService svc = new MyServiceLayer();
IInvoice invoice = svc.CreateInvoiceForCustomer(customer, items, paymentInfo);
InvoiceViewModel invoiceVm = Map(invoice);
return RedirectToAction("Display", "Invoice", invoiceVm);
```

You can picture that the service layer might do the following:

```
public ServiceResponse<Invoice> CreateInvoiceForCustomer(Customer customer, IEnumerable<InvoiceItem> items, PaymentInfo paymentInfo)
{
    using (var db = new MyContext())
    {
        db.Entry(customer).State = customer.ID == 0 : EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;

        var invoice = new Invoice
            {
                Customer = customer,
                InvoiceDate = _timeService.Now(),
                PaymentInfo = paymentInfo
            };
        foreach (var item in items)
            invoice.Items.Add(items);

        db.Invoices.Add(invoice);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return new SeviceResponse<Invoice> 
            {
                IsSuccess = true,
                Data = invoice
            };
    }

}
```

In this example, the UoW pattern acts as a replacement for a transaction. You get Atomicity without getting your hands dirty.

The real power of UoW is in a stateful system, like WPF, where you could have a long-lived context that is used to process an big Queue of commands that are executing asynchronously on a different thread.

Comment: In my case i am using Winforms and i need to access multiple repositories and keep the data sync'd between them, so i can query multiple repositories and synchronize the save on my Presenter. What you are saying is that i can do all of this "NoTracking" part in the repository, and i think that is correct. Although this doesn't give me a direct way to acomplish the "batch" part of the question, but i guess i could return a DTO from that repository with the values (or even a tuple). Just wanted to know how the rest of the world deals with it.

Comment: If you want to have repositories participate in a UnitOfWork then you'll have to employ your own UoW implementation at that level of abstraction. The alternative is to take the repositories out of the equation (or are you doing Domain Driven Design?). If you don't have a requirement for storing entities in a flat file, then there isn't much of a reason to make allowances for it in your design. In fact, this is another "rule" of coding - Y.A.G.N.I. - You ain't gonna need it (so don't write it).

Comment: I do have an abstraction for a unit of work. Right now the only implementation hides a DBContext object from EF. Anyway i guess you are right. I am not going to need it. I just have to keep the details of the persistence layer from leaking into the other layers. Anyway this is a pet project to learn the concepts of TDD, proper layering with MVP, EF, etc. Thank you for your help :)